# Music In JavaScript when on button click

Tags: javascript, html, github

When button onclick should work with this mp3 file which I have uploaded to GitHub. it wouldn't work even though I have tried even using the link thru `https://voca.ro/1dcHxW3v1oQA`

```js
function play() {
  var audio = new Audio('https://voca.ro/1dcHxW3v1oQA
');
 }
```

```html
<head>
<body>
<button onclick="play()">bwbfw</button>
</body>
</head>
```

with the code changed it still won't play

Comment: Start by using `<button onclick="play()">bwbfw</button>`

Comment: `/button onclick="play()">` um where did you learn that? Unlearn that :)

Comment: Github does not return the audio file so you will not be able to link to it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to the file and trigger `play()`

```js
function play() {
  var audio = new Audio('https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/1979.mp3');
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick=play()>bwbfw</button>
```

Comment: would the file be from github or a diffrent because when i tried this is didnt work to see the code go to here https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/

Comment: any file with .mp3 at the end should work
Edit: someone said github does not store server file, so try somewhere else instead of github

Comment: `https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/1979.mp3`

Comment: @Nahh no it will not ;) github does not server files.

Comment: @epascarello where did you find this link https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/1979.mp3

Comment: @epascarello oh didnt know that

Comment: @Bobzilla07 You put the link to the github.io page.... so you link to it based off your file directory..... Use that URL with this answer and it will magically play

Comment: @Nahh I made your code work, sorry if I hijacked our answer by making the edit for you.

Comment: @epascarello thats fine, as long as it helps the guy